# Xcode, images, core data, incompatible pointers, persisting image data

Tags: ios, image, pointers, core-data

I am very green to programming.
I am using a couple tutorials to build an app but have run into a problem.

I built both tutorial projects and they work.
I integrated them but running into some problems incorporating into the core data project.

Pt 1: The core data works and stores/displayes patient and prescription info.

Pt 2. camera / photo picker gives access to camera and photo library and displays it in the same view with patient or prescription info.

This all works BUT

When I go to add the image to the list of stuff to be saved I get: Incompatible pointer types assigning to NSString from UIImage

Sample Code:

```
- (IBAction)save:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {

    ////telling core data what information to save and what fields it came from. 
Corresponds with properties up in the text entry area.

    addPrescription.patient = prescriptionsPatient;

    addPrescription.prescriptionName = _prescriptionName.text;

    addPrescription.prescriptionInstructions = _prescriptionInstructions.text;

    addPrescription.scene = _scene.text;

    addPrescription.look = _lookimage.image;
```

---

i read a bunch of post on converting NSString to NSDAta for core data to play nice but they didnt seem to apply to what I was doing.

NOTE: my COre Data model has  2 entities and both have an attribute that I'd like to be an image (or its URL)
I have one as Binary Data and another as NSString so I can try to make it work either way using one OR the other.

Any help would be great.
Many thanks

Comment: Can you tell the type of addPrescription.look?

Comment: Why do you want to convent a NSString no NSData? You can store NSStrings directly. Do you mean UIImage?

Answer (score 0):

Go with the file path string being stored in Core Data and the image file being stored to disk.

Use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` to get the data from the image and `writeToFile:atomically:` to save that data to disk. Then use the file path with your managed object instance.